# How to represent word document structure as XML?

Tags: java, xml, ms-word

I have an application which converts word documents(after merging bookmarks) to PDF using OpenOffice Java API. 
First we upload the word files in the application (java based), then application processes it and generates PDF. 
I need to validate the word document structure (check for certain tables/bookmarks etc) while uploading the word file.

I was thinking representing word document structure as XML and then validate the same. 
I am wondering how can I represent word as XML ? I had a look at OpenXML but not sure whether its a right approach or not.

Expert suggestions/comments are welcome.

Thanks
Sumukh

Comment: XML is used as primitve structured data storage. How would you think, you would split your document into structured data format? By sentence? By word? By paragraph?

Comment: Maybe you will be better off reading the word file using some API(like the POI-XWPF) and then checking for the things you want.

Comment: When you say your application converts "word documents", are these binary .doc or OpenXML (.docx)?    If docx, this is a zipped up collection of xml documents.  Look at the document.xml part.  You can do that with an XML parser, or using docx4j (or POI).

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointers. I ended up creating a xml file manually which represents the word document structure. I am parsing the xml and comparing various bookmarks with those available in the word document.